# get text from desktop window using Winium

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way in [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop) to get text from an element in a Windows desktop app? The following script will successfully open Notepad and type out a note, but then it fails to read the text.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:9999',
    desired_capabilities={
        "debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false',
        "app": r"C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe"
    })

window = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Notepad")
window.send_keys("example text")
content = window.text()
```

This throws error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: NO GET TEXT`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
edit_element = window.find_element_by_class_name("Edit")
text = edit_element.get_attribute("Name")
print text
```

Answer (score 0):

In python

```
text = edit_element.get_attribute("Text")
```

c#

```
text = edit_element.Text
```

Comment: the question is not related to `C#` so why include that?